# Multiple Joins less cost way

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join

Below query has 3 tables where I have to do 2 joins to get a column information, It is very slow, is there any effective way to run this query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    st.status_c1
FROM
    schemaname.tablea st
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            lic.SpecId AS applicationid,
            lic.comData AS combusappid,
            lic.ageId,
            lic.licId,
            lic.licid,
            lic.appid,
            com.nybe_bustbl_id AS busid
        FROM
            schemaname.tableb lic
            INNER JOIN tablec com ON lic.comData = com.comData
        WHERE
            lic.ageId = '12'
    ) rt ON
        st.ageId = rt.ageId
    AND
        st.licId = rt.licId
    AND
        st.licid = rt.licid
    AND
        st.appid = rt.appid
WHERE
    status_id = 3;
```

Comment: With any performance problem you should consider how you would execute it, what table will you start with? How will you access the table with its filters? Then what table will you join to? Would you do a lookup for each row from your first query or would that end up doing so many small lookups that you might as well read from the next table using its other filters. Now that you’ve thought about it, check what Oracle though by looking at the execution plan, get the row source execution statistics too to see where all the work went.

Answer (score 2):

Your current query will create extra rows when the `JOIN` condition is met for multiple entries in either table and then `DISTINCT` will filter these duplicates out. You could try to cut down the amount of work filtering duplicates by using `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       st.status_c1
FROM   schemaname.tablea st
WHERE  status_id = 3
AND    EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   schemaname.tableb lic
  WHERE  lic.ageId = '12'
  AND    st.ageId = lic.ageId
  AND    st.licId = lic.licId
  AND    st.appid = lic.appid
  AND    EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM tablec com WHERE lic.comData = com.comData
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of redundancy in the query (licid is in the SELECT and ON twice) and you don't need to use subqueries for this.  I think this will work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT st.status_c1

FROM tablea st
  INNER JOIN tableb lic ON st.ageId = lic.ageId
                       AND st.licId = lic.licId
                       AND st.appid = lic.appid
  INNER JOIN tablec com ON lic.comData = com.comData

WHERE status_id = 3
  and lic.ageId = '12'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the update, but when I check the cost  I don't see any change in the cost and it does a full table scan for every table, is there a way we can reduce the cost?

Answer (score 0):

How frequently are you going to run this query, how much time is it taking now and what is the explectation. Are statistcs run on all tha tables.
There are many things which we can think of, but to start with if possible could you plese give ue the like the table structure and explain plan of the query.
Also  may be an index on status_c1 table tablea help.  As pointed out try removing the join  condition which is twice AND st.licid = rt.licid

```
SELECT DISTINCT  st.status_c1
FROM  schemaname.tablea st
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            lic.SpecId AS applicationid, lic.comData AS combusappid, lic.ageId, lic.licId, lic.licid,
            lic.appid, com.nybe_bustbl_id AS busid
        FROM schemaname.tableb lic
            INNER JOIN tablec com ON lic.comData = com.comData
        WHERE lic.ageId = '12'
    ) rt ON st.ageId = rt.ageId AND st.licId = rt.licId AND st.licid = rt.licid AND  st.appid = rt.appid
    WHERE status_id = 3;
```